# Changing permissions on FileZilla Server

Tags: permissions, filezilla, ftp

I've just setup a FileZilla Server on Windows,
every thing is going well, but, I cant change the file permissions.

When I'm using windows explorer I get this:

[image: Windows Explorer:Changing Permissions]

And when I'm using FileZilla FTP Client I get this response

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileZilla server does not support `SITE CHMOD` command.

It would not make sense anyway. FileZilla server is supported on Windows only. Unix style permissions does not make much sense on Windows.

Nor it supports any other way to change file permissions (not even Windows-style).

Comment: so there is no possible way to do it?

Comment: No. Updated my answer to make it explicit.

Comment: what if i used for example VMware and installed linux os and run an ftp server on it, will that work ?

Comment: Depends on what FTP server software you use. You should start a new question for this.